# Driving 8 Leds from 4 pins of microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, led, charlieplexing

Is it possible to drive 8 Leds with 4 pins of microcontroller according this picture? Only one Led has to light at the time. The rest two pins will be always high Z. I tried to simulate it, there is a loop around thru high Z buses but the voltage on glowing diode is split between 3 another, so they should be safety off. I don`t want charlieplexing because the lighting diode voltage is split between two diodes only (unsafety off). Is my consideration right?

[image]

Comment: Is your purpose to light up 8 leds individually using a limited set of IOs. If yes an easy way out is by using a GPIO extender connected to your microcontroller through a bus(like IIC).

Comment: Plus I am not sure how exactly do you plan to control the microcontroller's pin from being a output to a High Z. Which this is possible by setting the pin being an input and output, I am not sure if this is a good/standard practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly Charliplexing.

You can only have one LED illuminated at once, so you'd have to do a 1:8 multiplexing to give the appearance of any or all of the multiple LEDs simultaneously illuminated, meaning each LED might only get ~1mA average. That may be enough if your brightness requirements are modest and you use modern high-brightness LEDs.

Comment: Hi, charlieplexing can drive 12 leds with 4 pins, I don`t use all combinations like charlieplexing do. In my case i want drive small 2mA led at the time only, no need for switching combinations (or all led on). So I can avoid time multiplexing also.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický It's still charlieplexing, you are just not using all the combinations

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve can be accomplished using a demultiplexor such as the [74HC138](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc74hc138a-d.pdf). It will drive one of 8 outputs, which in your case would each have an LED and resistor. Only three select lines are needed to select between 8 LEDs. If you want to blank all the LEDs, you can tie your fourth pin to one of the enable inputs.

Also, not a big deal if this is the full scope of your project, but one benefit of using a chip like this (or other answers) is the power required from the uC is much lower than driving the LEDs themselves. Driving an LED requires milliamps, but the control signals for an IC like this are much, much smaller.

Comment: It is wearable low power device, I am limited in space. This is no adition costs also.